# New to data base, I am getting error this. How could i solve?

Tags: python, database

c.execute("INSERT INTO addresses VALUES (:f_name, :L_name, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode)",
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: addresses

i am trying to learn from a tutorial. Currently i am stuck here.

```
def submit():
    # clear the text boxes
    conn = sqlite3.connect('address_book.db')
    # create cursor
    c = conn.cursor()
    # insert to a table
    c.execute("INSERT INTO addresses VALUES (:f_name, :L_name, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode)",
    {
        'f_name': f_name.get(),
        'l_name': l_name.get(),
        'address': address.get(),
        'city': city.get(),
        'state': state.get(),
        'zipcode': zipcode.get()
    })


    conn.commit()
    # close Connection
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you’re trying to insert into `addresses` table.

The error `no such table: addresses` is saying that this table doesn’t exist.

You first need to create the table, before inserting into it. Like:

`CREATE TABLE addresses ( column1 datatype, column2 datatype, column3 datatype, .... );`

Or check if the original table you created is misspelled.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i spelled it wrong.